# How could I configure Slim micro framework in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, slim

How can I configure Slim framework in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find **CodeIgniter - Slim Framework - Doctrine** Configuration in this [Project](https://github.com/Drubo/research). You can fork the project from GitHub if you found it helpful.